# Swift Scale Animation is not animating view

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I would simply like to have a `pulsating UIView`. For that I have set up this:

```
let highlightView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .lightBlueCustom
    v.alpha = 0.9
    return v
}()

let scaleAnimation: CABasicAnimation = {
    let v = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    v.duration = 0.5
    v.repeatCount = .infinity
    v.autoreverses = true
    v.fromValue = 1.0
    v.toValue = 1.4
    return v
}()
```

And this is how I call it:

```
func showHighlightView(viewToHighlight: UIView, height: CGFloat) {
    self.view.addSubview(highlightView)
    highlightView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToHighlight.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    highlightView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: highlightView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    
    highlightView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToHighlight.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    highlightView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToHighlight.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    highlightView.layer.cornerRadius = height/2

    highlightView.layer.add(self.scaleAnimation, forKey: "scale")

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(viewToHighlight)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(highlightView)
}

func showWishIntro() {
    showHighlightView(viewToHighlight: self.addWishButton, height: 60)
}
```

But this is not working. It shows the `highlightView` correctly but there is no animation. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I fixed it... it was just a lucky guess but I am calling `showWishIntro` now in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and not it is working as expected. I have no idea why, so if anyone would care to explain just let me know :D I'm happy that it works.